# Equation (in text) is too long

Tags: math-mode, equations, text

I have a long math expression in the normal text, i.e. in the form $...$. 
 
 Unfortunately, the formula does not fit in the line of the text: 
It stands out sideways. \newline or \ do not help, because then there is a space in the line before, which I do not like.

Is there another solution?

Comment: There is no way of saying without seeing it but if a formula is so long it should be rather displayed than printed in-line.

Comment: Don't use `\left` and `\right` in your formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 

@campa: I do not want to display it as a formula, because it is just an explanation of the text in mathstyle, not a real "equation"

Comment: There _might_ be other solutions but as I already pointed out there is no way of telling without seeing the code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Could solve the problem by using \linebreak.